# Nuxt.js loading different component or page for the same route

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

**Background:**
I have a custom build CMS with built in modules for pages, publish/blog, products, shopping cart, etc. Admin is able to create any amount of pages, blog or product categories, subcategories...

Frontend needs to be modernized so we decided to go with Nuxt.js because we also need server side rendering support for ecommerce SEO purposes.

**Problem:**
There can be a route /blog/ that is only a simple cms page. But admin can also create a publish category with the same url (it that case, this URL/publish module has priority). Based on that URL I need to load different Nuxt page or component.

I need to be able to figure out which API to call based on that same URL. Each cms modul has separate api endpoint.

For example:
Pages /api/pages/?slug=blog
Publish /api/publish/?category=blog&per_page=10

**Real world example with solved problem:**
Simple CMS page: https://www.sprintersports.com/empresa
Category page: https://www.sprintersports.com/tienda-running

There is no /products or /category prefix to identify that second page needs to get different Nuxt component. Category can also in theory be just a simple page

**What I have tried:**

1. The first idea was to call publish api for each route. And if there are no results, try pages api.
2. Save all publish categories to store and on each route chage compare if category with the same url/slug exists. If not, call pages API

This works but it doesn't sound right to me from performance standpoint.

---

Any similar experiences or solutions?

I have tried to find solutions or examples with nuxt/vue+wordpress since there might be similar issues. But no luck so far.

Comment: What are the pages in your project, can you please display/list down them as well?

Comment: At the moment I have only one pages/default.vue page. All trafic goes through that page. Based on url/api response, I save content_type to store and dynamicaly load desired component based on that content type: cms/Default, publish/Index, etc.

Comment: I think there is a high probability that the logic that you have written to dynamically load any component is having some issue. Do you think you can post the code for that?